# Changing Listview Subitems colors

Tags: vb.net

I found excelsheet cell colors like This is it possible to do this in VB.net Listview ??

[image]

Comment: Everything is possible, but you should try find how to do it!

Comment: I can't view your image. Can you explain What you want?

Comment: @SATSON i want listview cells back color as per it's value

Comment: @Nadeem_MK yes but can you give any hint ??

Comment: No it means value contain in cell

Comment: @SATSON  Like 100 is maximum value than 100 = whole cell coloured, 50 then cell back color is half coloured

Comment: Try to add control progress bar in listview

Answer (score 1):

You need to code the ListView.DrawSubitem Event ([MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.drawsubitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

If you need to draw something complex, try to make a more specific question.

[image]

Here is the code for custom draw ListView SubItems.
(Create a form, insert a Listview called ListView1 and set the OwnerDraw property to True)

For the value-dependant drawing, you will need to use your coding skills, get lucky !!

Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D

Public Class Form2

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim itmX As ListViewItem
    For iRow As Integer = 0 To 10
        itmX = ListView1.Items.Add(iRow.ToString, iRow.ToString, "")
        For iCol As Integer = 1 To 3
            itmX.SubItems.Add(iCol.ToString)
        Next
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub ListView1_DrawColumnHeader(sender As Object, e As DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs) Handles ListView1.DrawColumnHeader
    e.DrawDefault = True
End Sub

Private Sub ListView1_DrawItem(sender As Object, e As DrawListViewItemEventArgs) Handles ListView1.DrawItem
    'e.DrawDefault = True
End Sub

Private Sub ListView1_DrawSubItem(sender As Object, e As DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs) Handles ListView1.DrawSubItem

    Dim rnd As New Random(Now.TimeOfDay.Milliseconds)

    Dim r As Integer = rnd.Next(0, 255)
    Dim g As Integer = rnd.Next(0, 255)
    Dim b As Integer = rnd.Next(0, 255)

    Using br As New LinearGradientBrush(New Point(0, e.Bounds.Height / 2), New Point(e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height / 2), Color.FromArgb(255, r, g, b), Color.Transparent)
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, e.SubItem.Bounds)
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, e.SubItem.Bounds)
        e.DrawText()
    End Using

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: No it is not that i want